# Using OpenCover coverage data with NDepend?

Tags: code-coverage, ndepend, opencover

My project uses OpenCover to analyse unit test coverage.

We've recently started using NDepend to improve the project. We're getting a lot out of it, but are stumped by one feature...

NDepend has functionality to incorporate data on code coverage into it's overall reports on technical debt. Unfortunately, [it can only consume reports from the following tools](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-coverage#Techno):

> NDepend can import coverage data from:
>
> - NCover™ 3.x and above coverage files
> - Visual Studio™ 2017, 2015, 2013, 2012 and 2010 XML coverage files
> - JetBrains DotCover™ 1.1 and above XML coverage files (with special NDepend formatting)

These are all commercial (i.e. paid-for) tools. As our project is open source, Open Cover (which itself is free as in beer as well as speech) suits our budget much better.

Is there any way to convert OpenCover reports into the format of one of the aforementioned tools? Or, is there some other way to squeeze data from OpenCover into NDepend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDepend v2019.1 now supports completely OpenCover coverage file format, more here https://www.ndepend.com/whatsnew#OpenCover
and here https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-coverage#OpenCoverFile

Answer (score 0):

You can convert OpenCover's coverage file to NCover format. That only requires basic XSLT code, as revealed in this discussion thread,

https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/568

Then things should work.

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea if it actually works? The linked thread seems to suggest that it is (at the very least) problematic. Have you used it?

Comment: The rule of open source is that hack the way out. If the transformation script was not perfect enough, you can try to tune it. There might be other scripts too.

Comment: That's my next move, yes. Unfortunately the resulting XML file didn't play nicely with NDepend. Don't suppose you have an example NCover file that I could use as a reference?